# javascript validation of existing class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on javascript conditions.

If the field is empty I open an alert, else the function gets executed.

But I am trying to add another condition -- to verify the class of the field. If it is not in the page, or if it's empty, then directly execute the function/show an error.

How can I check with javascript if the class is in the page and if it's filled ?

```
$("#bouton").on("click", function(){
    var warnning_message = 'warning message';

    if(!$('.the-class').val()) {
        alert(warnning_message);
    }
    else{
        console.log('ok');
    }
```

Comment: why that last `function`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems [**hasclass**](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) will be useful

```
if($('.the-class').val()==='' && $('.the-class').hasClass('className')) {
  alert(warnning_message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the existence of the class with `$(".the-class").length > 0` code:

```js
$("#botton").on( "click", function() {
    var warnning_message = 'warning message';

    if( $(".the-class").length > 0) {
        alert(warnning_message);
    }
    else {
        console.log('ok');
     }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="botton" class="the-class">Click Here</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check whether an element with specific class exists or not use the following:

```
if ($(".the-class").length>0){
    alert('Exists');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put ID to the field in order to select it and then do something like this:

```
if($( "#mydiv" ).hasClass( "the-class ))
   console.log('has class');
else
   console.log('no class');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the length of the array

```
if( $('.the-class').length == 0) {
   alert(warnning_message);
}
else if (!$('.the-class').val()){
   alert(warnning_message);
}
```